# Tic tac toe computer move

Tags: python, python-2.7

this is the code of computer move in the game tic tac toe in python:

```
def computermove(board,computer,human):
    movecom=''
    rmoves=rd(0,8)
    for movecom in legalmoves(board):
        board[movecom]=computer
        if winner(board)==computer: 
            return movecom
        board[movecom]=''
    for movecom in legalmoves(board):
        board[movecom]=human
        if winner(board)==human:  
            return movecom
        board[movecom]=''
    while rmoves not in legalmoves(board):
       rtmoves=rd(0,8)
    return rmoves
```

what is the use of `board[movecom]=''` in the for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code appears to try out different moves and sets each board position to either the computer or the human, and sees if that is a winning move.

Assuming that `legalmoves(board)` returns a list of positions that are *already* empty (set to `''`), the `board[movecom]=''` line then *resets* the board to the empty value again.

Personally, I'd alter the `winner()` function to take an additional parameters to set an extra human or computer position, to test if that would be extra position would constitute a winning move, rather than alter the board with trial positions.

Comment: What if instead of movecom='' in line 2 we use movecom=None.

Comment: The line can be removed altogether. It doesn't matter what you assign there as the `for` loop later rebinds the name.

Comment: Almost certainly; but there are not enough details here to say anything else. Python is very expressive, I am sure there are other approaches to the problem. You'll have to be a *lot* more explicit.

Comment: can you please again explain the meaning of  board[movecom]='' in the for loops. Is there any other alternative for it.

Comment: Without the rest of the code, there is not enough context here to go into any more detail than what I already gave.